# Factory Girl undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, rspec2

I have a controller spec something like this

```
describe :bizzaro_controller do

  let(:credit_card_account) { FactoryGirl.build :credit_card_account }

  it "doesn't blow up with just the stub" do
    CreditCardAccount.stub(:new).and_return(credit_card_account)
  end

  it "doesn't blow up" do
    credit_card_account
    CreditCardAccount.stub(:new).and_return(credit_card_account)
  end

end
```

Which results in this:

```
bizzaro_controller
  doesn't blow up with just the stub (FAILED - 1)
  doesn't blow up

Failures:

  1) bizzaro_controller doesn't blow up
     Failure/Error: let(:credit_card_account) { FactoryGirl.build :credit_card_account }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `exp_month=' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/user/bizzareo_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/user/bizzareo_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.23631 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

My credit card factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :credit_card_account do
    exp_month 10
    exp_year 2075
    number '3'
  end
end
```

My CreditCardAccount is an empty ActiveRecord::Base model

```
=> CreditCardAccount(id: integer, exp_month: integer, exp_year: integer, number: string)
```

Versions

```
0 HAL:0 work/complex_finance % bundle show rails rspec-rails factory_girl
/home/brundage/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@complex_finance/gems/rails-4.0.0
/home/brundage/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@complex_finance/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.0
/home/brundage/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@complex_finance/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0
```

Comment: all looks legit to me. Have you prepared your test database properly, ie. `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: Yeah. Did a `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:wipe db:migrate db:seed` before. (db:wipe is a custom task that just drops all the tables)

Comment: can you try actually running a `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: @sevenseacat Done. No change.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working. all points that your test database is not correct.

`RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create` will drop and recreate your test database. Then try to run your rspec using the rake command, in order to migrate the database: `rake rspec`

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't it.

Comment: @DeanBrundage sorry. Will let the answer there to possible help someone that google to here. Can you see this column in your test database? is your `db/schema.rb` correct?

Comment: See my reply to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but I think the cause of my problem was different. My solution, however, may perhaps be useful: I used the Fabrication gem (http://www.fabricationgem.org/) instead of FG.

The reason why I was having this problem was because I was trying to have FG create/build an object that was not ActiveRecord, it was only an ActiveModel, and it had to be initialized with arguments.

I didn't see in the Fabricator documentation an example totally like what I needed, but I got it with this syntax:

Fabricator(:my_class) do
  on_init do
    init_with("Company Name", "Fake second arg")
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that in model I made a private method called `:send` (forgot that it is already used in Ruby).